# Include external, non-compiled Header/Source in Eclipse/avr-gcc

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt, avr-gcc

I have a problem including an external header with the related .c-file ( both in a folder outside the project-folder) to an existing project.

I have several projects for Atmel AVR microcontrollers. Some of them are packaged into one Git-Repo as a logical unit (hardware-level).
Common headers and related Source-Files (e.g. twi, usart) are located in separate Git-Repos which are included as submodules.

Just to show quick what I am talking about, the project is set up like this (`-` = folder, `*` = file):

```
Git-repo_1
  -project_1 (avr-gcc)
      - config (header-files to be included in header-files in the common-folder; project-specific)
          * avr_twimaster_cfg.h
          * avr_twislave_cfg.h
      - share (header-files with project-specific definitions to be included in "project_[2:5]")
          * project_1_interface.h
      - Debug (Build-Config Folder with makefile)
          * makefile
      - Release (Build-Config Folder with makefile)
          * makefile
      * main.h (main project header, includes <avr_twimaster/avr_twimaster.h>, <avr_twimaster/avr_twimaster.h>)
      * main.c (main project source, includes "main.h")
      * functions.c (functions to be used in main.c, includes "main.h")
      * opt. more files
  - project_2 (avr-gcc)
  - project_3 (avr-gcc)
  - project_4 (avr-gcc)
  - project_5 (avr-gcc)
  - common (no toolchain)
      - avr_twimaster (Git-Submodule)
          * avr_twimaster.h (includes <avr_twimaster_cfg.h> from any project)
          * avr_twimaster.c (includes "avr_twimaster.h")
      - avr_twislave (Git-Submodule)
          * avr_twislave.h  (includes <avr_twislave_cfg.h> from any project)
          * avr_twislave.c  (includes "avr_twislave.h")
```

In "Project-Properties/C,C++ Build/Settings/Tool Settings/AVR Compiler/Directories" I added:

```
"../../common"
"../share"
"../config"
```

These paths are added to the makefile with -I e.g. "-I../config".

---

> NOTE: It is important that all paths are relative to the projectfolder
>   and are included in the makefile so the project can be compiled
>   without eclipse or with another computer with different paths.

My Problem:
Even eclipse seems to know where to look for the included header-files: When I ctrl-click on a function in "functions.c", I jump to the correct header "avr_twislave.h" in the "common"-path. But a ctrl-click on the function in the header does not jump to "avr_twislave.c" and vice verca. Functions are same in name and parameters. "avr_twislave.h" is included in "avr_twislave.c".

When I try to compile the project I get many errors "undefined reference to..." which is obvious since the connection between Header and Source is broken. Looking at the console, the errors happen in the linker section - but I don't know if the linker itself is the problem or it just cant link something that wasn't compiled by the compiler. In the compiler-output I don't see any section with the external header-files/source-files in the common-folder. Only source-files directly in the project-folder are compiled.

I spent several hours with this problem and read through many posts but have not found a solution that worked.

What I want:

- Tell avr-gcc (through eclipse) to use the header/source in the
  external folder.
- Folder setup is more or less critial, since the external headerfiles/sourcefiles should be used by all projects and within the Git-Repo as submodules. Putting the "libs" into the project-folders is not an option.
- Info about the "libs"/folders must be in the makefile or another file included by the makefile and not just inside eclipse
- Paths must be relative to project-folder/makefile-folder

What I already tried:

- Paths in "Tool Settings / AVR Compiler / Directories" work for the Index (at least the header).
- Paths in "AVR Assembler"
- Paths in "AVR C Linker"
- countless variations how to include the external headers from within the project-files
- Paths under "Paths and Symbols" seem to be the same as in the Toolchain-Options and were added automatically.
- Linked Resources seem to be absolute in path
- Environment Variables also seem to be absolute

Please let me know if my question needs some clarification or additional info.

Comment: I think i found the mistake. Embarrassing but it seems that eclipse (me) forgot to add the Folders to the "Source Locations" under "Paths and Symbols". Setting the Paths in the compiler settings (-I option) only includes the Header-Files. I add an answer when i fully checked this.